# Extracting a subset of character form a word with R

Tags: r, character, extract

I need to create a function which extracts and changes a part a of word. It would be to convert Unicode to a specific form of UTF-8.

My input would be for instance

```
word = "Aul<U+00E9>n"
```

My output would be

```
f(word) = "Aul%c3%a9n"
```

I don't know how to select only the `<U+00E9>` part in the first word.

Does anyone have a idea how to do that ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: this: `sub("<U.+>", "%c3%a9", "Aul<U+00E9>n")` works

Comment: @CathG I guess the unicode might change. For example, `U+00EC` should be changed for `%c3%ac`.

Comment: @Pascal I guess so too but the OP didn't tell how the replacement part works considering the pattern part so I just provided a way to capture the pattern part

Comment: you can also go with `sub("[^<]*(<U.+>)[^>]+", "\\1", "Aul<U+00E9>n")` if you want to get the code as result in order (for example) to match it later with something in a "table"

Comment: @CathG  Is-it possible to do something like `sub("<U+00E9>","%c3%a9",word)` ?Thanks for your answers =).

Comment: yes of course but you'll get the exact same result than with my first proposition (except for the value of `word`). You probably have a lot of codes to "translate" ? I don't think you want to do it manually, one by one ? (well I hope you don't)

Comment: In fact I just have French/German accents to change which means about 10 different unicodes to change. I do not see any other solutions :(.  This code `sub("<U+00E9>","%c3%a9", "Aul<U+00E9>n"` and I do not understand why. Thks for your precious help =)

Comment: you could have a data.frame with 1st column giving the unicode and 2nd one giving the UTF-8 equivalent. Then you extract the unicode part from the word, look for the UTF-8 match and put it in replacement of the unicode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too long for comment but what I meant in my last comment is:

you can build a correspondences data.frame like:

```
corresp <- data.frame(uni=c("<U+00E9>", "U+00EC"), utf=c("%c3%a9", "%c3%ac"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Then you can define a recode function, e.g. like:

```
recode <- function(word, corresp){
              code <- sub("[^<]*(<U.+>)[^>]+", "\\1", word)
              m_code <- corresp$utf[corresp$uni==code]
              return(sub(code, m_code, word))
          }
```

And so:

```
recode("Aul<U+00E9>n", corresp)
#[1] "Aul%c3%a9n"
```

Comment: It doesn't cover all the unicode escape characters.

Comment: Nice function (+1) without using any external packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, please `install.packages("Unicode")` before run.

```
word = "Aul<U+00E9>n"
start<-regexpr("<.*?>",word)
end<-a+attr(x = a,which = "match.length")
unipart<-Unicode::u_char_inspect(substr(word,start+3,end-2))[3]
paste(substr(word,1,start-1),paste("%",paste(iconv(unipart,toRaw = T)[[1]],collapse="%"),sep=""),substr(word,end,nchar(word)),sep = "")

>[1] "Aul%c3%a9n"
```

Comment: no need to install a special package when the OP said he had 10 unicodes to change (that he already knows and he knows the utf-8 equivalent). Before answering, it can be a good idea to read carefully a question and any precision given in comments. Also, except if you don't want your answer to look too much like mine, please use `sub` instead of this messy `substr` / `paste` combination